# Controlar velocidad de una nave y hacer que se mueva por si sola c++

Tags: c++

quisiera saber si alguien me podría explicar dos cosas, la primera hacer una nave que se mueva sola hasta una coordenada x,y, la segunda como puedo hacer para controlar la velocidad de la nave, mi profesor de programación me dijo que usara algo de time, pero estuve investigando y no encontré como controlar la velocidad.

Aquí esta mi intento del código, mi lógica es que las variables bool controlen el movimiento arriba, abajo, izquierda derecha.

Nueva info (Pregunta editada)

**ESPECIFICACIONES**

Como voy empezando en esto de programación orientada a objetos me va costar entender ciertas cosas, pero voy a hacer un esfuerzo por entender lo mejor posible (por ejemplo aun tengo problemas con establecer parámetros tanto por valor como por referencia).

Mi nave debe poder moverse en vertical y horizontal.

Debe ir de una coordenada x hasta una nueva coordenada x, o de una coordenada y a una nueva coordenada y.

Cuando llegue a esa nueva coordenada voy a poner que sea su límite y ese límite va a cambiar la trayectoria de la nave.

Digamos que primero aumenta en y++ y al topar ese límite cambia a x++, antes no hice esta especificación y yo confundí con eso, una disculpa, debe poder moverse en todas direcciones, pero no en horizontal.

Debo controlar que esta nave cambie de dirección cuando yo establezca su limite, por eso puse variables de tipo bool (las voy a poner comentadas para especificar), voy a poner mi código abajo del otro al cual le moví un poco pero no conseguí mucho.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
}
class Nave{
    public:
        int x,y;
        bool izqder;
        bool arrab = false;
        void imprime();
        void borrar();
};

void Nave::imprime(){
    system("color 0A");
    gotoxy(x,y); cout<<("** **");
    gotoxy(x,y+1); cout<<(" *** ");
    gotoxy(x,y+2); cout<<("  *  ");
}


void Nave::borrar(){
    gotoxy(x,y); cout<<"     "<<endl;
    gotoxy(x,y+1); cout<<"     "<<endl;
    gotoxy(x,y+2); cout<<"     "<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    system("mode con: cols=100 lines=50");
    Nave nave1;
        nave1.x=8; nave1.y=5;
        nave1.imprime();
    while(nave1.arrab = false){
        for(nave1.y; nave1.y<=50; nave1.y++){
            nave1.borrar();
                if(nave1.arrab == 50){
                nave1.arrab=true;
                }
            nave1.imprime();
        }
    }

    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

ESTE ES EL CODIGO NUEVO

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <conio.h>
        #include "windows.h"
        #include <stdio.h>

        using namespace std;

        void gotoxy(int x, int y){
            HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            COORD dwPos;
            dwPos.X = x;
            dwPos.Y = y;
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
        }
        class Nave{
            public:
                int x,y;
                float velocidad; //Vairable sugerida agregada
                bool izqder; //Variable para controlar eje x
                bool arrab; //Variable para controlar eje y
                void imprime();
                void borrar();
        };

        void Nave::imprime(){
            system("color 0A");
            gotoxy(x,y); cout<<("** **");
            gotoxy(x,y+1); cout<<(" *** ");
            gotoxy(x,y+2); cout<<("  *  ");
        }


        void Nave::borrar(){
            gotoxy(x,y); cout<<"     "<<endl;
            gotoxy(x,y+1); cout<<"     "<<endl;
            gotoxy(x,y+2); cout<<"     "<<endl;
        }

    /*Intente meter este fragmento (aporte de @PaperBirdMaster) 
pero no logré nada, no supe adpatarlo por cuiertas cosas que 
detallaré ahi mismo marcadas con un @ para distinguir que es mi comentario*/
    /*
    void mover_nave(Nave &nave, const Posicion &destino)
    //@No entiendo como funciona & en el parametro.
    //@No se para que sirve const
    {
        // Comprueba si la nave ya esta en su destino
        if (nave.posicion.x != destino.x && nave.posicion.y != destino.y)
        {
            /* Calcula cuanto tiempo ha pasado desde que se actualizo la nave
            por ultima vez. */
            auto ahora = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            std::chrono::duration<float> tiempo_pasado = ahora - nave.ultima_actualizacion;
/*@NO tengo ni la minima idea de como funciona este fragmento anterior
no se que sea todo esto de chrono*/

            // Calcula cuanto se habra desplazado la nave dada su velocidad.
            float desplazamiento = nave.velocidad * tiempo_pasado.count();

            // Usar trigonometria para calcular cuanto se desplaza la nave en cada eje.
            ...

            // Actualizar el estado.
            nave.ultima_actualizacion = ahora;
        }
    }
    */
        int main()
        {
            system("mode con: cols=100 lines=50");
            Nave nave1;
                nave1.x=8; nave1.y=5;
                nave1.imprime();
                nave1.arrab = false;
                for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
                    nave1.borrar();
                    gotoxy(nave1.x,nave1.y+i);
                    nave1.imprime();
                    Sleep(100);
                /*Con este for conseguí que el cursor se mueva hacia abajo, 
mas no conseguí que mi nave se moviera, 
me está fallando la lógica por en mi mente esto si funcionaría de esta manera*/


               }


            system("pause>nul");
            return 0;
        }
```

Nota: 
aun no agregué cosas relacionadas al de tiempo porque no entendí muy bien como funcionaban, por lo tanto puse un Sleep, y yo pensaba controlar la velocidad con los Sleep, pero mi profesor me dijo que los hiciera con time (lo cual es algo que aun no conozco por eso pensaba usar Sleep).

Espero que ahora lo entiendan mejor y haya alguien que me pueda apoyar, muchas gracias a los que ya me hicieron su aportación.

Comment: Te recomendaría que simplificaras aún mas tu pregunta. A primera vista son dos preguntas. Una es cómo definir una trayectoria de un punto (x, y) a un punto (x1, y1). La otra pregunta es como controlar la velocidad de dicho trazado.

Comment: Respecto a la trayectoria, cómo es que necesitas que sea? Requieres de una trayectoria mínima (diagonal)? Puede ser dibujando un rectángulo?

Comment: En cuanto a la velocidad, cuáles son tus requerimientos en cuanto a presición? Puede ser tan simple como las velocidades de una licuadora o la velocidad de un automóvil.

Comment: Requieren ser trayectorias en vertical y horizontal, mi nave va a hacer dos recorridos preestablecidos, cuando recorra la trayectoria completa en el primero va a pasar al segundo (que va a ser diferente) pero esta vez va a avanzar mas rápido.

Answer (score 5):

No puedes controlar la velocidad de algo que se mueva por pantalla sin primero entender el concepto de [Fotogramas por segundo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fotogramas_por_segundo), copio de la wikipedia:

> **Fotogramas por segundo**, también llamada **tasa de refresco**, **imágenes por segundo**, **cuadros por segundo**, FPS (del inglés «frames per second») o **framerate**, es la velocidad (tasa) a la cual un dispositivo muestra imágenes llamadas cuadros o [fotogramas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fotograma).

Es decir, la velocidad de cualquier cosa que quieras mover por pantalla estará ligada a la velocidad que tu programa refresque los datos, tanto los lógicos como los visuales.

#### Propuesta.

Añade a tu objeto `Nave` un valor de velocidad, te aconsejo que este valor represente cuántas celdas (caracteres) se mueve por segundo y que éste sea un valor en coma flotante. Así pues un valor de `1.5f` significará que se moverá una celda y media por segundo (si tuviese que desplazarse 3 celdas tardaría dos segundos).

También necesitarás almacenar cuándo fue actualizada la nave por última vez, para calcular cuánto se habría desplazado desde la última actualización. Te aconsejo que sea de tipo [`std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point).

---

Crea un objeto `Posicion` que almacena posiciones en pantalla:

```
struct Posicion { float x{}, y{}; };
```

Lo puedes usar como miembro de tu nave en lugar de almacenar las coordenadas por separado. Usa números en coma flotante para poder almacenar trayectorias intermedias (si en un fotograma se desplaza menos de una celda el desplazamiento debe almacenarse aunque visualmente no provoque ningún cambio).

---

Crea un método `mover_nave` (llámalo como quieras) que dada una nave y una posición mueva la nave proveída una cantidad de celdas calculada en base a la velocidad de la nave:

```
void mover_nave(Nave &nave, const Posicion &destino)
{
    // Comprueba si la nave ya esta en su destino
    if (nave.posicion.x != destino.x && nave.posicion.y != destino.y)
    {
        /* Calcula cuanto tiempo ha pasado desde que se actualizo la nave
        por ultima vez. */
        auto ahora = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<float> tiempo_pasado = ahora - nave.ultima_actualizacion;

        // Calcula cuanto se habra desplazado la nave dada su velocidad.
        float desplazamiento = nave.velocidad * tiempo_pasado.count();

        // Usar trigonometria para calcular cuanto se desplaza la nave en cada eje.
        ...

        // Actualizar el estado.
        nave.ultima_actualizacion = ahora;
    }
}
```

Una vez conoces el desplazamiento de ese fotograma, debes usar Pitágoras para saber cuánto se mueve en cada eje:

[image]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación @PaperBirdMaster no entiendo muy bien porque apenas entré a esto de las clases o POO y aun me cuesta entender o dominar ciertas cosas y hay otras que aun no conozco, Esto fue un error mio porque no especifiqué en mi pregunta y soy principiante, veo que se requiere ser mucho mas especifico a la hora de este tipo de dudas. Por esto aun no he llegado a una conclusión en mi programa, dejame aclarar bien editando la publicación y a ver si consigo una solución, igual gracias por esta info porque me imagino que en un futuro me servirá.

Comment: @AxelA te he intentado presentar un código lo más genérico posible, debería poderse usar incluso en la nueva situación que propones (si he entendido bien tus nuevas especificaciones).